After upgrade serenity to version 4.1.10 test report is not generated correctly, I get an error on test scenario details
After upgrading serenity to 4.1.10, junit 5  and java to version 21 the serenity report is not generated correctly. When clicking on scenario link from generated report to see the details I'm getting the error
"NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
status code: 404, request id: 806WFWKCBT5R3W18, host id: YvSr5k8vq1dnmgRlD4G59VIxjg8d2kg6UKwtdHgXnKxoEk9rvk1KTjCU8ZdcfYbeFynHsONCoG0="
I am using Junit5, Serenity 4.1.10, Java 21 and gradle.
I am expecting to see test result details when clicking on scenario link
the build.gradle file


plugins {
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "8.6"
    id "net.serenity-bdd.serenity-gradle-plugin" version "4.1.10"
    id "java"
    id "idea"
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '4.0.0'
    id "org.gradle.test-retry" version "1.5.9"
}

group = 'com.fanduel.fgp'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

defaultTasks 'clean', 'test', 'aggregate'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    slf4jVersion = '2.0.13'
    serenityCoreVersion = '4.1.10'
    serenityCucumberVersion = '4.1.10'
    junitVersion = '5.11.0-M1'
    junitLauncher = '1.11.0-M1'
    assertJVersion = '3.25.3'
    logbackVersion = '1.5.6'
    jacksonVersion = '2.17.0'
    jacksonDataFormatVersion = '2.17.0'
    serenityVersion = '5:4.1.10'
    aws_version = '2.20.103'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:${jacksonVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:${jacksonVersion}"
    implementation group: 'org.jboss.aerogear', name: 'aerogear-otp-java', version: '1.0.0'
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.32"

    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenityCoreVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-rest:${serenityCoreVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-ensure:${serenityCoreVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:${junitLauncher}"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:${junitVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertJVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:${jacksonDataFormatVersion}"

    testImplementation platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:${aws_version}")
    testImplementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3'
    testImplementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sts'
}

test {
    testlogger {
        theme 'standard-parallel' // task level
    }
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    def test_suite = System.getenv().get("TEST_FLAG")
    retry {
        maxRetries = 1
        maxFailures = 10
    }
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags 'org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled'

        if ((test_suite != null) && (test_suite != "full_suite")) {
            def tags = test_suite.replace(',', ' & ')
            includeTags tags
        }
    }
}

gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
test.finalizedBy(aggregate)




Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
